# Better way to combine variables in panel dataset in R?

Tags: r, function, panel-data

I'm working with panel data where some of the questionnaire items get asked only once while most others are asked several times across different waves. So let's assume there I have survey responses on a categorical variable.

Even though it's likely panelists will be stable in their reponse on a given question, it may occur that they change their opinion, or even drop out of the panel. Others might enter the panel at a later point in time (in a later wave).

So let's say this leads to a dataset which looks like this, where var_1a and var_1b are two variables that measure the same thing just in two different waves:

```
mydata<-data.frame(
  var_1a = c(1,2,3,4,5,NA),
  var_1b = c(1,2,5,5,NA,NA)
)
```

Now I would like to automatically combine these variables into one single variable across the two waves. As a condition, I would like to take the mean if respondents have changed their opinion from one wave to the other. Furthermore, I would like to keep the reponse from wave 1 even if the respondent has droped out of the panel in wave 2.

The way I have been doing this in R is by using this function:

```
combo<-function(x,...){
  V<-rowMeans(x[, c(...) ], na.rm=T) * 
    ifelse(rowMeans(is.na(x[, c(...) ])) == ncol(x[, c(...) ]), NA, 1)
  ifelse(is.nan(V),NA,V)}
```

For some reason, this introduces "NaN" if all variables are consistently NA across all waves, hence the last line of code in the function.

This works just fine and I get what I wanted:

```
> mydata$combo_var<-combo(mydata, c("var_1a","var_1b"))
> mydata

   var_1a var_1b combo_var
1       1      1       1.0
2       2      2       2.0
3       3     -3       0.0
4       4      9       6.5
5       5     NA       5.0
6      NA     NA        NA
7      NA     NA        NA
8      NA     NA        NA
9      NA     NA        NA
10     NA     NA        NA
```

However, I was wondering if there's a better and easier way to do this. Is there a way I could use dplyr to do the same? Any tidyverse solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some `tidyverse` options:

Data

```
mydata <- data.frame(
  var_1a = c(1,2,3,4,5,NA),
  var_1b = c(1,2,5,5,NA,NA)
)
```

### Option 1

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mydata <- mydata %>% 
  mutate(
    combo_var = pmap_dbl(select(., contains("var")), 
                     ~mean(c(...), na.rm = T))
    )
```

Result:

```
 var_1a var_1b combo_var
1      1      1       1.0
2      2      2       2.0
3      3      5       4.0
4      4      5       4.5
5      5     NA       5.0
6     NA     NA       NaN
```

### Option 2

```
mydata <- mydata %>% 
  mutate(
    combo_var = rowMeans(select(., contains("var")), na.rm = T)
    )
```

Result:

```
 var_1a var_1b combo_var
1      1      1       1.0
2      2      2       2.0
3      3      5       4.0
4      4      5       4.5
5      5     NA       5.0
6     NA     NA       NaN
```

Comment: Okay thanks. But do you know why `NaN` gets introducted instead of just NAs?

Comment: NaN (not a number) happens typically when a calculation is carried out, but the result cannot be represented numerically. If we have set `na.rm = F`, it would have return `NA` for rows 5 and 6. Since we told `rowMeans` to remove NAs, we basically have a result that cannot be computed, so NaN. The key here is that the value is not *missing* but cannot be calculated.

Comment: small change to the `pmap` option

Answer (score 1):

You could express this a little more clearer by avoiding the `ifelse`s.

```
combo2 <- function(dat, sset) {
  r <- rowMeans(dat[sset], na.rm=TRUE)
  r[is.nan(r)] <- NA
  return(r)
}
mydata1$combo_var <- combo2(mydata1, c("var_1a", "var_1b"))

#    var_1a var_1b combo_var
# 1       1      1       1.0
# 2       2      2       2.0
# 3       3     -3       0.0
# 4       4      9       6.5
# 5       5     NA       5.0
# 6      NA     NA        NA
# 7      NA     NA        NA
# 8      NA     NA        NA
# 9      NA     NA        NA
# 10     NA     NA        NA
```

#### Data

```
mydata1 <- structure(list(var_1a = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), var_1b = c(1L, 2L, -3L, 9L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```